# Understanding IP trace results - disconnecting from EA servers on PS4

Tags: ip

Morning all,

I am at my wits end.

I am getting kicked out of EA servers every ten minutes for the last 2 days.

I have 40MBp/s broadband and I am wired directly into the console. All other internet services in my house, phone, tablets, Netflix, smart TV's, etc. are working fine with no issue.

There has never been any outages of the PSN or EA servers during the times I have had issue.

Here are the steps I have taken so far:

- Reset router and power cycle
- Factory default settings
- Updated firmware
- Re-opened ports (as suggested by EA)
- Added PS4 into the DMZ (as suggested by EA)
- Ran 2 x Traces of my IP (using UO Trace)
- Reset PS4 to factory default

*Trace*:

```
Host Name IP Address Hop Ping Time Ping Avg % Loss Pkts r/s Ping best/worst
* Unknown Host * 0.0.0.0 1 0ms
host-212-158-250-39.dslgb.com 212.158.250.39 2 10ms 100% 0 / 101
* Unknown Host * 63.130.104.202 3 9ms 100% 0 / 101
ae1.126.man.cw.net 195.89.96.113 4 10ms 10ms 0% 101 / 101 9ms / 24ms
ae0-ucr1.mcr.cw.net 195.2.28.70 5 10ms 10ms 0% 101 / 101 8ms / 18ms
ae16-xcr1.lnt.cw.net 195.2.27.165 6 18ms 16ms 0% 101 / 101 14ms / 22ms
ae3-xcr1.lsw.cw.net 195.2.30.53 7 17ms 15ms 0% 101 / 101 14ms / 45ms
as6461-gw-xcr2.lsw.cw.net 195.2.2.118 8 16ms 15ms 0% 101 / 101 14ms / 22ms
ae6.mpr3.lhr3.uk.zip.zayo.com 64.125.21.21 9 15ms 15ms 0% 101 / 101 13ms / 22ms
ae12.mpr2.lhr2.uk.zip.zayo.com 64.125.28.21 10 15ms 15ms 0% 101 / 101 14ms / 33ms
ae27.cs1.lhr11.uk.eth.zayo.com 64.125.30.236 11 87ms 100% 0 / 101
ae5.cs1.lga5.us.eth.zayo.com 64.125.29.126 12 88ms 100% 0 / 101
ae4.cs1.dca2.us.eth.zayo.com 64.125.29.203 13 88ms 100% 0 / 100
ae27.cr1.dca2.us.zip.zayo.com 64.125.30.247 14 88ms 89ms 0% 100 / 100 86ms / 203ms
ae22.er2.iad10.us.zip.zayo.com 64.125.29.121 15 86ms 88ms 0% 100 / 100 86ms / 165ms
64.125.199.190.t00673-02.above.ne64.125.199.190 16 87ms 88ms 0% 100 / 100 87ms / 137ms
* Unknown Host * 159.153.92.98 17 86ms 87ms 0% 100 / 100 86ms / 132ms
* Unknown Host * 159.153.92.94 18 86ms 87ms 0% 100 / 100 86ms / 167ms
easo.ea.com 159.153.64.173 19 87ms 87ms 0% 100 / 100 86ms / 101ms
```

I am being told by EA that the issues lie with my ISP and that they need to open ports for me, or reroute connection around the hops that are coming up as `Unknown Host`.

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: Sounds like the EA tech support person doesn't know how to interpret traceroute results, either...

Comment: Do you know anything I can do to help my issue? do you understand that traceroute result?